# Angular5 - basic callback understanding

Tags: angular, callback

I have a websocketService in which I have a `send()`-method:

```
sendQuery() {  
    ....

    this.wsConnection = new WebSocket(this.url);
    this.wsConnection.onopen = () => this.wsConnection.send(reqObj);
    this.wsConnection.onerror = event => console.log('A Error has occured!');
    this.wsConnection.onclose = event => console.log('Connection closed');
    this.wsConnection.onmessage = (event) => {
      this.result = JSON.parse(event.data);

      // return here ? no way, this only exits the onmessage()
    };
    // return here? nope.. stayes undefined as the onmessage runs async
}
```

I do trigger this method from a component, in which the websocketService is injected in. Now I would need to get a return from `onmessage()` to the parent component.

I am searching for days now, but I can't find a solution, how this could be done. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Comment: why dont you use the angular http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of this is happening asynchronously, you'll need to create an `Observable` that the component can subscribe to. Then in your callback you would `next` or `complete` the observable.

Something like:

```
sendQuery(): Observable<MyType> {
   return Observable.create(s => {
      //All your code
      ws.onmessage(msg => {
          s.next(msg);
          s.complete(); //If you are done with the observable
      }
   });
}
```

That being said, its odd that you would open and close a WS connection for just one query. After all, the whole point of WS is to be *persistent*. In that case I would have a `Subject` (which kind depends on your needs) as a service property that is exposed as an `Observable` and `onmessage` fires it's `next` whenever it has data.